# Script batch para renomear extensão de arquivos de maneira recursiva

Tags: windows, batch

Preciso de um script em bat que permita renomear todos os arquivos com EXTENSÃO *.rar para *.cbr , precisa renomear qualquer arquivo nas subpastas partir do diretorio raiz  D:\Downloads.

O comando que fiz tá assim ( ren *.rar *.cbr) Desse jeito apenas renome-a arquivos da raiz mas não os que vem a seguir nas subpastas.

Como são muitas subpastas, o ideal é que o script seja recursivo, a fim de visitar todas as subpastas dentro da raiz.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o comando `for`.
Veja se este exemplo satisfaz as suas necessidades:

```
CD D:\Downloads\
For /R %%G in (*.rar) do Echo REN "%%G" "%%~nG.cbr"
```

O parâmetro `/R` irá tornar o for recursivo, de modo que irá percorrer todas as subpastas.

[Link de referência](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)

Answer (score 0):

---

O comando **`where`** retorna listando o caminho completo dos arquivos, capture essa saída num **`for`** para renomear as **extensão**.

Uma opção de um looping **`for`** com o **`where`** **recursivo=/r** para **renomear** as **extensão**

---

```bat
:: No arquivo bat/cmd :: 
   @echo off
   for /f "tokens=*" %&i in ('where /r "D:\Download" "*.rar"')do rename "%%~i" "%%~ni.cbr"  

:: Na linha de comando :: 
   for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('where /r "D:\Download" "*.rar"')do @rename "%~i" "%~ni.cbr"
```

---

**1.** Tente obter o **caminho** e **nome** de **arquivo** **alvo** num **`For`** usando **`/F`** + **`Dir /S`**...

**2.** No comando **`CD`** adicione **`/D`** (**entra** e permanece no **Drive** e **Diretório** rodando os comandos no **Drive e Diretório** apontado no comando.

---

**Na linha de comando:**

---

```bat
CD /D D:\Downloads\ 
For /F "tokens=*" %i in ('^<nul dir /o-d /on /b /S "*.rar"')do rename "%~i" "%~ni.cbr"
```

**No arquivo bat/cmd:**

---

```bat
CD /D D:\Downloads\ 
For /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('^<nul Dir /o-d /on /b /S "*.rar"')do rename "%%~i" "%%~ni.cbr"
```

Answer (score -4):

O BAT renomeador de arquivos dentro de várias pastas funciona 100% criei apartir destes exemplos aqui mostrados :: for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('where /r "G:\TXT" "*.txt.igvm"') do rename "%~i" "%~ni." (A ideia aqui seriaé renomear anulando a extenção .igvm do rensomware)

Devido um problema de rensomware, este vírus que criptografa os arquivos mais comuns acrescentando a extensão .igvm .  Consegui renomear todos arquivos usando este BAT, para depois tentar recuperar o forma original dos arquivos .txt com (EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard) para serem abertos novamente pelo bloco de notas do windows. Mas não tive êxito na restauração dos meus arquivos pessoais. Obrigado a todos que contribuíram neste post.

globodepre@gmail.com